# Can't copy/paste text resources from Translation Editor in Android Studio 3.2

Tags: android, localization

I remember old Android Studio version is possible to copy (CTRT+C) all text values from Translation Editor then paste (CTRT+V) to Google Sheet. But it is impossible until Android Studio 3.2 . 
How can we export all text values to Google Sheet (and vice versa)for support translating?